# Redirect for special characters

Tags: redirects

I want to set a redirect as below.

`http://www.domain.com/course/view.php?id=2` **TO** `http://www.domain.com/course/view.php?id=2&section=1`

Can you please let me know how can this be set ?

Comment: Have you tried straight 301 redirect set in htaccess file?

Comment: Please include what you have tried already...

Comment: I tried the redirect from cPanel. From cPanel it does not accepts the ? & =.

Comment: What web server are you using? I am assuming Apache. Would I be right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You could do it in the PHP itself**

`<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.domain.com/course/view.php?id=2&section=1"); 
?>`

**You could do it with mod_rewrite**

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2$
RewriteRule ^/?course/view\.php$ http://www.domain.com/course/view.php?id=2&section=1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: Hi Brett. It worked like a charm. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

In .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =id=2
RewriteRule ^course/view\.php /course/view.php?section=1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

If the query string matches exactly `id=2` then externally redirect. The `QSA` flag combines the original query string with the new one, so the resulting URL is actually `?section=1&id=2` - but the order should not matter.

The other niggling thought is that you would perhaps be better handling the defaulting of URL params in your server-side code and set a `rel="canonical"` tag instead of redirecting.

**UPDATE:**

> I tried the redirect from cPanel. From cPanel it does not accepts the ? & =

The redirection tool in cPanel can only handle simple redirects and to be honest I would avoid it if at all possible. When you add a redirect in cPanel it edits your .htaccess file. If you already have other directives in your .htaccess file then it has to be very clever not to break anything - and it does not appear to be that clever.

This no doubt depends on cPanel versions, but I tried to create a suitable redirect in cPanel. It didn't complain about the query string characters `?` and `&` and allowed me to create the redirect. However, when examining the resulting directives in .htaccess it was completely wrong and would not have worked as intended!